# How to align floating label, value and underline in Material Spinner

Tags: android, css, android-layout, android-spinner

I'm using material spinner from https://github.com/ganfra/MaterialSpinner. 
I'm trying to make the floating label, the spinner value align with the spinner's underline. Is it possible to achieve this? I tried adding padding or margin to the xml, but it only resulted the whole spinner to be move.
I'm new to android. Your advice and guides are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

I want to achieve something like **this**. So that it will be aligned with my edittext.
[image]

```
<fr.ganfra.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/InputLabel"
    android:id="@+id/spinner4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:ms_typeface="fonts/OpenSans-Semibold.ttf"
    app:ms_hint="@string/kategori_premis"
    app:ms_alignLabels="true"
    app:ms_hintTextSize="18sp"
    app:ms_baseColor="@color/colorControlNormal"
    app:ms_multiline="false" />
```

Comment: add this  `app:ms_floatingLabelText="floating label"` `app:ms_floatingLabelColor="@color/floating_label"`

Comment: @VishvaDave already did... but only the floating label aligned with the underline. The value wasn't.